# Query with aggregate, subquery and group by not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you help me, please? I spent about 2 hours to understand what is wrong, but still don't.

> SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name
>   'id'

```
select count(*) as aggregate
from (
    select `cities`.*,
        `cities`.`id` as `id`,
        `cities`.`country_id` as `country_id`,
        `cities`.`name` as `name`,
        `cities`.`alias` as `alias`,
        `cities`.`active_frontend` as `active_frontend`
    from `cities`
    where (
            cities.alias in (
                select `alias`
                from `cities`
                group by `alias`
                having COUNT(`alias`) > 1
                )
            )
    ) count_row_table
```

Don't ask me what the hell is going on please. Biggest part of this query is generated by Laravel.

If I delete this part:

> where
>   (cities.alias IN (SELECT `alias` FROM `cities` GROUP BY `alias` HAVING
>   COUNT(`alias`) > 1))

It will work. But I need this part af.

Comment: Remove `cities.*,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `cities.*`.

But you can simplify your query to:

```
select sum(cnt) as cnt
from (
    select COUNT(alias) as cnt
    from cities
    group by alias
    having COUNT(alias) > 1
    ) t
```

and avoid re-reading your table because in the end, all your need is total number of rows for which alias has more than one row.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing `cities.*` solved the problem.And I can't change all query as you wrote because Laravel (php framework) makes it, not me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to materialize a subquery for this.  You can do:

```
select count(*)
from cities c
where exists (select 1 from cities c2 where c2.alias = c.alias and c2.id <> c.id);
```

With an index on `cities(alias, id)`, this should have better performance.